Activation function : tanh(z) in binary classification
I use the tanh activation function in binary classification, but I don't know how to process the loss function. Here is my code
class TanhNeuron():
    def __init__(self): # w : increase, b: section
        self.w=None
        self.b=None

    def forpass(self,x): 
        z=np.sum(x*self.w)+self.b
        return z
    
    def backprop(self,x,err): # gradient
        w_grad=x*err
        b_grad=1*err
        return w_grad,b_grad
    
    def activation(self,z): #activation function : tanh(z)
        a=np.tanh(z)
        return a
    
    def fit(self,x,y,epochs=1000):
        self.w=np.ones(x.shape[1]) 
        self.b=0                    
        for i in range(epochs):
            for x_i,y_i in zip(x,y):
                z=self.forpass(x_i)
                a=self.activation(z)
                err=-(y_i/a+(y_i-1)/(1-a))*(1-a**2)    #Here is the problem...
                w_grad,b_grad=self.backprop(x_i,err)
                self.w-=w_grad
                self.b-=b_grad
    
    def predict(self,x):
        z=[self.forpass(x_i) for x_i in x]
        a=self.activation(np.array(z))
        return a>0.5

I printed the accuracy using a test case. Here is my code.
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

cancer=load_breast_cancer()

x=cancer.data
y=cancer.target
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,stratify=y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

tanhneuron=TanhNeuron()
tanhneuron.fit(x_train,y_train)
print(np.mean(tanhneuron.predict(x_test)==y_test))

An accuracy of 0.36 was output.
This means that no learning has occurred.
